# GLSL share uniforms among programs #130

Tags: opengl, glsl, legacy

i'm currently trying to figure out, how I share a uniform between shaders in old GLSL.
Sticking 'shared' in front of the uniform didn't compile.
**Edit:** I know the scope of a uniform is one program.
An example for this could be the modeliew-projection-matrix. One wouldn't want to set it for each program individually but only once.

Is there a way to do it?

This is the (vertex-)shader code:

```
#version 130
in vec4 position;
in float size;
in vec4 incol;
out vec4 color;
shared uniform ivec4 relWorldOffset;
uniform vec4[14] cubestrip;
uint cubeindex;
void main()
{
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix
   * (cubestrip[cubeindex] * size
   + relWorldOffset + position);
  cubeindex++;
  color = incol;
  cubeindex %= 14U;
```

This is the error:

```
0:6(1): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER, expecting $end
```

Comment: By sharing do you mean declare the variable once and use it in different shaders of a same draw call?

Comment: Ok, let me clarify: Sharing means having the same uniform declaration for different vertex-shaders in different programs. Changing is only necessary in one shader-program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `shared` keyword like that in GLSL. You are probably looking for *uniform blocks* or *uniform buffer objects (UBO)*. According to [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), they require OpenGL version 3.1 (so GLSL `#version 140` or higher is required). If that's not a problem, the [GLSL syntax](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)) would be as follows:

```
uniform MatrixBlock
{
    mat4 projection;
    mat4 modelview;
};
```

Also, take a look at [this tutorial](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Positioning/Tutorial%2003.html) and [GLSL 1.40 specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.40.pdf) (chapter 4.3.5.1) for more pointers.

(EDIT: Actually, `shared` keyword is defined in most recent OpenGL versions, but it is only used as a layout qualifier in compute shaders to make variable shared within a workgroup.)

Comment: This was the thing!
I had to add "#extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : enable" because i'm on intel hardware

Comment: @Banyoghurt: It is not the fact that you are on Intel hardware that you have to do this. It is actually because Uniform Buffer Objects are not defined in GLSL 1.30. A compliant GLSL compiler will not allow you to use them without the `#extension ...` directive when you tell it you are compiling a GLSL 1.30 shader. Some vendors are more compliant than others, but this is not something that happens merely because you are using Intel hardware.